# Nokogiri encoding square brackets when reading html string

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using nokogiri to read the contents of a file and perform some replace operations. At the end, I get the content back as string, using doc.to_s.

I have simplified the code to as follows

```
html_string = '<a href="[foo]">foo</a>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_string)
doc.to_s
```

The output I get is

```
<a href=\"%5Bfoo%5D\">foo</a>
```

What I want is to leave the square brackets in tact. Note, when the square brackets are not an attribute of a HTML tag, they are not encoded.

Any ideas as to how I can get around this?

Comment: Technically square brackets are not supposed to be in a URL like that, so Nokogiri is just adhering to the standard. The set of permissible characters is actually pretty small.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to prevent Nokogiri from doing this, since Nokogiri is designed to produce correct HTML output. The best solution I can think of is to post-process the output from Nokogiri:

```
doc_str = '<a href="%5Bfoo%5D">foo</a>'
doc_str.gsub!( /%5B(.+?)%5D/i, '[\1]' )
# => <a href="[foo]">foo</a>
```

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: That could cause all kinds of problems if you're not careful, so don't apply to too liberally.

Comment: It sure could. Be careful. (This is the reason most templating engines use placeholders like `{{this}}`, because that's a lot less likely to appear in the wild than single square brackets.)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it more simple.

```
 CGI.unescape(doc.to_s)
```

Comment: Sure, if you want no URL-escaped characters to ever appear anywhere in your document. Seems like overkill when we're only concerned with two characters that always appear in pairs.

Comment: This might be a good answer if you apply it only to the `href`s

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a simliar problem, and although square brackets are not *valid* in hrefs there are cases where they are used.  In my case I need to preserve them to be compatible with a customer's systems.

2 Useful facts:

1 - Nokogiri corrects the HREF when it converts the document to text.  If you load in an html fragment and look at the href you'll see that the square brackets are there.

2 - Removing square brackets only happens to href attributes,  they're allowed in other attributes.  For example data-raw-href

So if you load in a document and then copy the href attribute you can preserve the original.  You still need a post process on the final text to convert data-raw-href back to href.

An example (which you can try in irb)

```
require 'nokogiri'
doctext = '<html><body><a href="[my dodgy href]">link text</a></body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(doctext)
a_tag = doc.css('a')[0]
 a_tag['data-raw-href'] = a_tag['href']
doc.to_s
```

Yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<a href="%5Bmy%20dodgy%20href%5D" data-raw-href="[my dodgy href]">link text</a>
</body></html>
```